# Devise redirect to custom login page (Regular and Admin Section)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have started a Rails project with Devise for authantication system. But in my scenerio, there is also an admin section. So both admin and regular users use the "User" model, which was created by Devise. I added "is_admin" field to Model with migrations. But this time i have 2 main problems.

First one is, i need to have a login page in admin section, which will use the Devise's login methods and if the user authanticate and look for the "is_admin" field to redirect user to admin pages.

Second one is, there should be another login page for the regular site, which people will see. This will not look for the "is_admin" field and will use regular Devise login forms.

So are these possible with Devise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application controller place an after_sign_in function as below that would check for the user role and then redirect

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_admin?
      redirect_to admin_path
    else
      redirect_to user_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can i detect if the user hits "/admin" and i want to redirect user to the login page for the admin section? In my AdminController i have "before_action :authenticate_user!" but it redirects to "/users/sign_in".

Comment: Does both the admin and user have different login pages? You can overwrite the authenitcate_user! function to check for similar condition there.

Comment: Yes they have different login pages. I'll check in admin login page if the user has "is_admin: true" then will redirect_to admin panel, if "false" will not have acccess to the admin section. So i have to write a helper for it?

Comment: I suggest you skip_before_action authenitcate_user! in the admin controller and then write your custom private function in the controller to redirect to the admin login page as he is now in the url pointing to that controller.